# no decode delegate for this image format `PNG' ImageMagick CentOS

Tags: php, centos, imagemagick

I'm trying to use ImageMagick in CentOS to generate pdf documents and convert PNG images. ImageMagic is already installed and imagic extension is loaded and working in PHP 5.5 but when I try to generate PDF or convert images I get the follow error: 
**no decode delegate for this image format `PNG'**

I've already installed libpng and reinstalled ImageMagic but the problem continues

Comment: do a `convert -list delegate`. if png isn't listed, then IM hasn't picked up on the png library

Comment: I ran the command and I get this  about PNG:   png<= webp      "cwebp" -quiet -q %Q "%i" -o "%o"

Comment: that's weird. webp is for VP8 compression.

Comment: So, is here something wrong with my ImageMagick installation?

Comment: looks like, at least with the png definition. do you even have a `webp` binary on the system? not that it'd be useful in producing pngs, but at least it'd explain why you get the delegate error

Comment: @MarcB: Not weird at all. It means that there is the `cwebp` command available which can convert ***to*** PNG. `cwebp` doesn't need the PNG lib.

Comment: that'd explain it, but still... weird.